# Magento2: GA standard module does not see the ecommerce transaction

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I configured the Google Analytics module in the Magento backend. Then I enabled e-commerce tracking in GA.

Now, I see the number of page visits, but I do not see e-commerce transactions.
Can anyone help how to solve this?

version: 2.2.5